# Semantic UI in Rails Stylesheet could not be loaded. A lot of errors in parsing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm working on a Rails app that uses Semantic UI as its frontend framework.

I'm using Rails 5.

I followed the instructions on this site (https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Rails-LESS) to include the gems needed for Semantic to work on Rails.

In my html.erb file (the left portion of the photo), I've used some Semantic UI buttons, just to test out if Semantic loads.

I believe it loaded, but I'm getting a bunch of errors in my console (+ it is saying on the top right that the Style sheet could not be loaded).

What seems to be the problem?

[image: Photo showing Error]

**EDIT**

I was able remove the 'Style sheet could not be loaded' error by lowering my 'sprockets' gem version to 3.6.3, instead of 3.7.1. (I'm not sure if this is a safe way of doing it, though. There were warning of deprecated methods in the sprockets, so people were suggesting to use version 3.6.3 instead.) However, the other errors in the console log still remained.

**EDIT 2**

The 'Style sheet could not be loaded' error still remained.

**EDIT 3**

I switched to the sass version of Semantic UI, and the "Style sheet could not be loaded" error is now gone! But, the console still had the "error in parsing values" error. I still don't know what is causing this. Any thoughts/fixes to this?

Comment: do I still need to @import "semantic" or something like that in my css?

Comment: Rails by default uses sass, not less, have you checked to ensure the less-rails gem is installed? It may be that the assets aren't being compiled/included since less isn't part of the pipeline. I've never tried the less version, but I know with the sass version that you do in-fact need the import statement.

Comment: would it be better to use the sass version of semantic ui, instead of less? I used less because the gem came from Semantic-UI themselves.

Comment: The sass version isn't official, but it is still regularly maintained, the only caveat is that you'll lose themes except for the default, but in my usage that's never really mattered, since you can still customize all of the variables. I would suggest just adding less-rails to your gemfile and seeing if that fixes the issue first, if not, try the sass version.

Comment: @DivXZero I switched to the sass version, followed the directions, and the "Stylesheet could not be loaded" error is now gone!! But the console still had those "error in parsing values" error. Would you know what is causing this?

Comment: It looks like there may be invalid CSS somewhere, either an unsupported attribute (some browser specific attributes will also throw errors if they aren't enclosed in a conditional), or even something like an extra semicolon or something. It could be difficult to track down manually. I'd suggest running `rake assets:precompile` and look into any errors it outputs. If it compiles fine, paste the generated css into a validator and dig deeper from there. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en

Comment: the invalid CSS could be from the semantic ui itself? I didn't put any other css code except Semantic UI

Answer (score 2):

Since Rails 5.1 you can use `yarn` to integrate Semantic UI with your app. Here's how I've done it. Process is not perfect (you still have to run `rails tmp:clear` after changing your theme files), but it gives you advantage of using the latest `semantic-ui` package and not being dependent on gem updates.

### Using

- Ruby: 2.5.1
- Rails: 5.2.0

### Create a new rails app

```
$ rails new semantic_integration
$ cd semantic_integration
$ bundle install
```

create `semantic.json` in your app directory

```
{
  "base": "app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui",

  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config"      : "src/theme.config",
      "definitions" : "src/definitions/",
      "site"        : "src/site/",
      "themes"      : "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged"     : "dist/",
      "uncompressed" : "dist/components/",
      "compressed"   : "dist/components/",
      "themes"       : "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean"        : "dist/"
  },

  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": true,
  "rtl": false,
  "version": "2.3.1"
}
```

run `$ yarn add semantic-ui`.
This will install `semantic-ui` in `app/assets/semantic`

Add followin lines to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
# semantic-ui assets
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'semantic')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'semantic', 'semantic-ui', 'src', 'themes', 'default')
```

Add Semantic UI css

```css
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
*= require 'semantic-ui/src/semantic'
```

Add Semantic UI js

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
// after turbolinks

//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui/dist/semantic
```

Add `init.js` and require it in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

window.App || (window.App = {});

```
App.init = function() {
  // here goes Semantic UI component initialisation
  // i.e.
  $('.ui.menu .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    on: 'hover'
  });
  $('.ui.menu a.item')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this)
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('active');
  });
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  App.init();
});
```

In you Gemfile add:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
```

and run `bundle install`

Now you app should be able to compile Semantic UI less files.
If you're getting error:

```
expected ')' got 'o'
```

go to `app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui/src/theme.less`
and remove `(optional)` keywords on `@import` statements

---

### Icon font

go to: `app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui/src/site/globals/site.variables`
and add:

```
/* Fonts */
@fontPath  : "assets/fonts";
```

then go to: `app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui/src/site/elements/icon.variables`
and add:

```
/*******************************
             Icon
*******************************/

/*--------------
   Font Files
---------------*/
@fontName: 'icons';
@src:
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.woff2") format('woff2'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.woff") format('woff'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.ttf") format('truetype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.svg#icons") format('svg')
;
@fallbackSRC: font-url("@{fontPath}/@{fontName}.eot");

/*--------------
 Optional Files
---------------*/

/* Outline Icons */
@importOutlineIcons: true;
@outlineFontName: 'outline-icons';
@outlineSrc:
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.woff2") format('woff2'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.woff") format('woff'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.ttf") format('truetype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.svg#icons") format('svg')
;
@outlineFallbackSRC: font-url("@{fontPath}/@{outlineFontName}.eot");

/* Brand Icons */
@importBrandIcons: true;
@brandFontName: 'brand-icons';
@brandSrc:
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.woff2") format('woff2'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.woff") format('woff'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.ttf") format('truetype'),
  font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.svg#icons") format('svg')
;
@brandFallbackSRC: font-url("@{fontPath}/@{brandFontName}.eot");
```

---

## Important!

> For some reason `less-rails` gem monitors changes to
>   `app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui/src/semantic.less` but not any other
>   files in `app/assets/semantic/semantic-ui/src` folder. After changin
>   `*.variables`, `*.overrides`, or `*.config` files run `rails tmp:clear` or manually delete `tmp/cache/assets` folder.

---

## Demo App

https://github.com/ziinfo/semantic_integration.git