# what is causing Less::Error 'Unrecognised input'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, yarnpkg

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50086486/2009652) about using yarn to set up semantic-ui with rails but get this vague error that says only `Unrecognised input` whenever I access localhost. The stack trace is short and the only clue it provides is to the stylesheet and javascript link tags in my application.html.erb head:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

What does `Unrecognised input` mean, and what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

who would win? many lines of code or one missing semicolon?

make sure you end your variable declarations with a semicolon.